# Prototype Ajax request limitation?

Tags: javascript, ajax, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs

I am learning about he Prototype Ajax API. I was reading their documentation and I saw this:

> Remember that for security reasons (that is preventing cross-site
>   scripting attacks) Ajax requests can only be made to URLs of the same
>   protocol, host and port of the page containing the Ajax request. Some
>   browsers might allow arbitrary URLs, but you shouldn't rely on support
>   for this.

So does this mean that I can't make requests to a backend of one app from another of my apps? Or am I just misunderstanding this. I would really appreciate some clarification for a new javascript learner, like me. Thanks

Comment: If you are making an [offline web app](http://diveintohtml5.org/offline.html) then there is no need to worry, it is still the same domain despite being 'served' locally. However you may want to put the AJAX URL in the `NETWORK` manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [same domain origin policy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is enforced by web browsers, for security reasons.

In short, without this restrictions, ajax requests would allow you to retrieve any web page on the behalf of the user. This would allow you to read his emails if he was logged-in on his webmail.

Take a look at [JSONP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSONP), for doing cross-domain ajax requests. (Notice the P in JSONP.)

This seems to be adding JSONP support to Prototype: http://dandean.com/jsonp-for-prototypejs/

Comment: thanks for the response. However, what if I want to make a request from a mobile application to the backend of my site. The mobile app is obviously is not the same host. So how are things like that handled? Or am I not understanding properly?

Comment: Read the answer entirely ;-) (hint: jsonp)

Comment: A relevant side question: So then do all third party APIs (for example like the flickr api) use JSONP or is that handled differently?

Comment: Yes, it very probably uses JSONP